# How do I display the formatted timestamp in a hoverable data point in a Flot line chart?

Tags: javascript, canvas, flot

Currently my line graph displays the properly formatted timestamp from the JSON data set along the x-axis.

example:

```
xaxis: { mode:"time", timeformat: "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%p"}
```

The output is something like:

**2010/12/6 05:32:32pm**

I also have my data points hoverable.

When I hover over the data points it displays

**(1291656755000, 1368ms)**

Where **1291656755000** is the original time stamp in milliseconds.

I'd like it where **1291656755000** is displayed as **2010/12/6 05:32:32pm** like it is in the x-axis when I hover over the data point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code where you generate the tooltip, call the flot formatDate function before passing the value to the tooltip function:

```
$.plot.formatDate = function(d, fmt, monthNames)
```

Where d is the date, fmt is your format string, and monthNames is optional.

You would call it like this:

```
var formattedDateString = $.plot.formatDate(d, "%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S%p");
```

If this doesn't make sense, post your tooltip code.